# Print certain amount of tuples in a list without name

Tags: python, list

so my exercise was to print 10 most common words in a text file.
Assuming I opened the file and created a dictionary that contains seperated words with indexes.
Normally, I do this:

```
li=list()
for key,value in d.items():
   tpl=(value,key)
   li.append(tpl)

li=sorted(li,reverse=True)
for key,value in li[:10]:
   print('Ten most common words: ',value,key)
```

But prof gave me a single line of code that can replace almost all those lines:

```
print(sorted([(value,key) for key,value in d.items()],reverse=True))
```

However I can't find a way to print only 10 tuples since the list has no name, I can't use the for loop to print. Can you help me out?

Comment: First argument of sorted has a list, you need to do list slicing so only top 10 gets printed like : print(sorted([(value,key) for key,value in d.items()][:10],reverse=True))

Comment: So you're saying you don't understand the way you normally do it?

Comment: @HetalThaker Wouldn't it be better to take the top 10 *after* sorting?

Comment: @HetalThaker thanks but it only run for the first 10 key-value pair in the list

Comment: @Manuel Yes i agree thanks for pointing out, it should be print(sorted([(value,key) for key,value in d.items()],reverse=True)[:10])

Comment: @user15420849 yes i have a new comment please check which will sort and then prints top 10.

Comment: @HetalThaker hey thanks, it's a nice and really short code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Separate the list creation from the `print()`:

```py
li = sorted([(value, key) for key, value in d.items()], reverse=True)
```

Now you can iterate through `li`.

```py
for item in li[:10]:
    print(item)
```

Comment: thank you it worked. I'm so stupid at this.
Edit: I don't know why I upvoted your answer and it shows -1...